# Moving Endnotes section in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

pulling my hair out here.
I formatted an entire book (350 pages) inside MS Word - almost everything went OK (except managing "sections" can be frustrating).  But ... I have 10 chapters, and created endnotes (several hundred) that appear, chapter by chapter, at the END of the book (right now).

I don't want the endnotes the the VERY end of the book - 2 other sections logically go before the endnotes (for instance the index should be the last part of the book).  MS word will not let me add ANYTHING after the endnotes section,

So how do I MOVE the endnotes section?

I have already tried to go to the endnotes dialog ... but the only options I have are to place the endnotes at the end of EACH section (chapter) or at the end of the document.

Ideally, I could just convert the endnotes into it's own section and cut and paste (move it).  But I cannot

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set endnotes to be placed at the end of each section and then supress endnotes in every section apart from the section after which you want them to appear. In this way they will be placed in only one place. After this section you can then create new sections.

See details:

[I need to put a bibliography after my endnotes, but Word won’t let me.](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/Formatting/FootnoteFAQ.htm#TextAfterNotes)[Archive Link](http://web.archive.org/web/20220219104200/https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/Formatting/FootnoteFAQ.htm)

Comment: Thanks ... Holy cow - what a convoluted process  0 and counterintuitive and awful UX by microsoft. At first I thought it was not a solution and was about to blame the answerer for not understanding the question - but it is really microsoft's fault for making this so bad that even a good workaround is hard to explain. Thanks!

Comment: I ad the same problem.  An internet search did not help at all.  Thank you very much  for this answer!

Comment: I added my own answer, but this answer would be improved by including relevant instructions and then giving credit to an external site instead of just linking. The link was broken before I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use section breaks, you can place endnotes at the end of a section instead of the end of the document.

On the References tab, select the pop-out arrow on the bottom right of the Footnotes section. This will open additional options for Footnotes & Endnotes. On the drop-down next to Endnotes Word gives you the option to change between "End of Document" or "End of Section."

To create the section break, decide where you want the endnotes.

Place your edit cursor where you want the endnotes to appear, and add a new section by using the Layout > Breaks option.

Word has several options for section breaks, such as also starting a new page or adding a blank page to start on either an even or odd page (useful for print layouts).

Section break instructions with pictures in [this Microsoft article.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-a-section-break-eef20fd8-e38c-4ba6-a027-e503bdf8375c)

Comment: Added more detailed answer that doesn't require going to an outside resource.